# Javascript - Desconstructing menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, menu, split

I have a menu with images that does an animation when the mouse is over one and out of the images (for each one).

The code is:

```
var nav = $('.menu');
nav.navs({
    useHash:true,
    defHash: '#!/page_splash',
    //myComm - Menus Hover In 
    hoverIn:function(li){
            $('a>span', li).stop().animate({'marginTop': -400},1000,'easeInOutExpo');
            $('a>strong',li).stop().animate({height:0},800,'easeInOutExpo');
    },
    //myComm - Menus Hover Out 
    hoverOut:function(li){
        if ((!li.hasClass('with_ul')) || (!li.hasClass('sfHover'))) {
            $('a>span', li).stop().animate({'marginTop': marOver},1600,'easeOutElastic');
            $('a>strong',li).stop().animate({height:414},1200,'easeOutBounce');
        }
    }
})
.navs(function(n){  

    $('#content').tabs(n);
});
```

But I need to do the function separately, one function for each item of the menu.

Comment: Worst title I've ever seen, 2 tags and a made up word.

Comment: I don't really get your question

Comment: well, the code is a function to do the mouse hoverin, hoverout of the menu, you can see it here
http://www.sapias-vinhos.com/Working/index.html.
But what I need is to have the function do the same effect but in a separate way, the function now takes the active menu and executes, but I need a function for each menu item. Did I explain well this time? thank you