# replace the "." into [dots] in multiple urls at a string

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, optimization, logic

i want to replace the "." into tokens like [dot] from below input to below output

input

> this is a test.for a question. at stackoverflow.com the best place to learn. programming. test www.wikipedia.com

output

> this is a test.for a question. at stackoverflow[dot]com the best place to learn. programming. test www[dot]wikipedia[dot]com

problems

1. there is a possibly `test.for` we cant use good regex like `/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}/gi` i think its best for using something like below better
2. maybe i found a solution;

`found = string.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.(com|co\.cc)|more\.domains)/gi);`

this work great, i have a problem to join/replace them to the original string. any  workarounds like [how can we filter elements in array with regex in array with javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13107078/how-can-we-filter-elements-in-array-with-regex-in-array-with-javascript)

how would you tackle this problem? btw im using nodejs other language is acceptable.

thanks

Comment: What about `www.stackoverflow.com`?

Comment: yeah that can count. sorry for the lack of information. but no http:// etc

Comment: But should it be `www[dot]stackoverflow[dot]com` or `www.stackoverflow[dot]com`?

Comment: the www[dot]stackoverflow[dot]com. btw that was fast!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This handles `www.example.com` correctly:

```
tld = ["com", "org", "edu", "net"] // feel free to add more

var input = "this is a test.for a question. at www.stackoverflow.com " 
    + "the best place to learn. "
    + "programming.test wikipedia.com and windows.microsoft.edu";


re = new RegExp('\\S+\\.(' + tld.join('|') + ')\\b', 'g')

var dotted = input.replace(re, function($0) {
    return $0.replace(/\./g, "[dot]");
});

// this is a test.for a question. at www[dot]stackoverflow[dot]com the best place to learn. 
// programming.test wikipedia[dot]com and windows[dot]microsoft[dot]edu
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var input = "this is a test.for a question. at stackoverflow.com the best place to learn. programming. test wikipedia.com";
var dotted = input.replace(/(\S+)\.(com|org|edu|net)\b/gi, '$1[dot]$2');
// "this is a test.for a question. at stackoverflow[dot]com the best place to learn. programming. test wikipedia[dot]com"
```

Comment: how about the www[dot]wikipedia[dot].com something like `/\b(\S+)\.(com|org|edu|net)\b|\bwww\.(\S+){3,}\.(com|org|edu|net)\b/gi, 'www[dot]$1[dot]$2'` (still working on it)

Comment: edit* we can do something like dotted.replace(/\bwww\.(\S+)\b/gi, 'www[dot]$1');` :) is there anotherway?